# Can we add some iron nanowires into type II superconductors to improve their performance?

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

Type II superconductors are widely used in electromagnets because these superconductors can be partially infiltrated by magnetic field. Magnetic field penetrates the material as discrete flux tubes, which allows electric currents to flow between them with zero resistance. However, as electric currents flow through, they exert a Lorentz force that pushes the flux tubes to move which causes energy dissipation. To prevent this from happening, impurities are introduced. These impurities can trap the flux tubes and reduce energy dissipation, but the flux tubes can still escape slowly due to thermal excitation.
[image]
So I come up with an interesting idea. Can we add some iron nanowires of a diameter comparable to the flux tubes into the superconductors to allow flux tubes to pass through them? Soft magnets have extremely high permeability, which means the energy of magnetic field is much lower in these materials. When they are put under magnetic field, they attract magnetic flux strongly to pass through them. Does that mean iron nanowires will greatly improve the flux pinning and the barrier to escape, thereby enabling superconductor magnets to operate under higher temperatures?